# Changing Image on Image View on click

Tags: android, imageview, lazy-loading, android-imageview, android-lazyloading

change image on image view when click on next and prev button and image is coming from url.

i have try to change image from below method but this is not changing image.

```
  imageLoader.displayImage(img[0], imgProperty);
```

**imgProperty** is a imageview and **img[0]** having a url and displayImage is the method of  Lazy loading Imagloader  class.

Please help me how can change Image view image on click.

[image]

Comment: You can use `ViewPager` for it. `img[0]` only will display your first image. For your requirentment you need to take one int variable and compare it with your arraylist. And on next  Button click increment that int variable and on prev button click decrement that int variable.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta Net and prev button is working fine, we can get incremented url on onclick but we can't change image on image view

Comment: On your Next-previous button click you also need to load your image in image loader class like  imageLoader.displayImage(img[your Integer variable], imgProperty);

Comment: i try  but image is not changing

Comment: After click on next Button while you increment your integer variable , then are you passing that variable to your int array?. Here img[incremented int variable]?

Comment: yes i am doing like this but did not change image,  There is any way to make dynamic multiple image view and load image at same time    and change image view on click event

Comment: Check this link http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-image-fragment-pager-view/. This is not for server image. But can get idea from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure `img[0]` refer to the image's URL.

And use  `imageLoader.displayImage` method instead of `imageLoader.DisplayImage` (capital D)

Comment: Try to call requestLayout method, change the image and call  invalidate method